How to ask for app permissions in React native apps?
I am trying to implement app permissions for my react native application and I am following the docs properly.
My Goal: I want to ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission from the users.
Upon calling below function the value of granted is always coming as "never_ask_again" and permission dialogue is not opening at all.
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

const requestWriteExternalStoragePermission = async () => {
  try {
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
      {
        title: 'Allow to write files.',
        message: 'This app need write permission in order to manage temporary files downloads.',
        buttonNeutral: 'Ask Me Later',
        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
        buttonPositive: 'OK',
      },
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('rest of logic...');
    } else {
      console.log('WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission denied');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.warn(err);
  }
};

Also AndroidManifest.xml looks like below.
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

Also in app setting Permissions are blocked. enter image description here
i Have tried uninstall the app and reset cache as well. Also tried ./gradlew clean, but it was not worked as well. can someone please help to resolve this issue. Many thanks in advance.
